# Laravel 5.2 : Extending Blade by passing an object instead of a string

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5

I want to add some blade directives.

I have in my service provider

```
Blade::directive('image', function ($media) {
    return "<?php echo {$media->getImageUrl()}; ?>";
});
```

The blade file contain

```
@image($media)
```

the $media variable is an object which use the `Media` model and which contains a `public function getImageUrl()`which return a string with the url of the image.

When I execute this code, I have this error message

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getImageUrl() on string
```

The object passed in the Blade directive is considered as a string instead of Media object

Is there any way to use $media as an `Media`object instead of a string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The curly braces should be around `$media`:

```php
Blade::directive('image', function ($media) {
    return "<?php echo {$media}->getImageUrl(); ?>";
});
```

This compiles to:

`<?php echo ($media)->getImageUrl(); ?>`

As far as I know Blade directives only accept one expression as a string, including the function call braces. So the expression received by the directive is:

`"($media)"`

After changing directives you should clear the compiled views because Blade is caching the directives, so you would not see your changes taking affect.